# Nerdtree, Rake 'require' cannot load file error

Tags: vim, rubygems

Gents,
  When trying to install NERDTree, I get the following error, suggestions?  Running from an AWS Amazon linux ami:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr  2 10:33 autoload
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr  2 10:23 doc
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr  2 10:23 nerdtree_plugin
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr  2 10:23 plugin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 4800 Apr  2 10:23 README.markdown
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr  2 10:23 syntax
[ec2-user@ip-10-194-186-112 nerdtree]$ rake
/usr/share/rubygems1.9/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file     -- rake (LoadError)
from /usr/share/rubygems1.9/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/bin/rake:30:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instructions have changed....

Install Pathogen

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle; \
curl -Sso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
https://raw.github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Install Nerd Tree

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git
```

:NERDTree

You may need to add the following to .vimrc:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```